# Lock session for multiple user in mysql (via python)

Tags: python

is there a good way to lock a mysql database, so that one and the same user cannot login multiple times with the same credentials?

I use simple python code to read and write data to the database. I have only one mysql user (others would be too complicated). But every session of the python code with this user allows write access. This shall not be possible - only for the first one until he´s logged out or that it´s general impossible to login, as long as a session is opened.

I use mysql 8.0

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Comment: This is where an application layer comes in as it allows for way more fine-grained control over access. The database limits *allowed operations*, not *connections*.

Comment: This seems like something you should be doing in the application, using lock files to keep multiple instances of the program from running simultaneously.

Comment: Are you going to prevent simultaneous login with same credentials from different devices?

Comment: In relational databases locks are a way to manage concurrent data modifications. They are not designed to handle application logic. Most of the time an application user is not the same as the database user anyway. Handle this in the application layer.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does have per-user connection limits, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-resources.html

```
CREATE USER 'teq508'@'%' WITH MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 1;
```

But that applies to *MySQL users*, not your application user. You said your application uses a single MySQL user for all application users. This is a common pattern.

If you want to limit a given application user to 1 session at a time, you would have to code that enforcement yourself.

For example, in the login code of your Python app, check to see if a session already exists for that user in whatever session cache you use.

When a user logs out, be sure to delete that session from the session cache, so that user can log in again later.

Inevitably, the deletion step will fail sometimes, and you'll have to have a process for the administrator to manually delete a user's session.